# Val in Lombok produces "incompatible types" error in IntelliJ but still compiles fine

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok

I found this piece of code:

```
Class<? extends Enum> enumClass = Class.forName(Charsets.class.getName())
                                       .asSubclass(Enum.class);
```

and I wanted to refactor it using Lombok, but something unexpected happened. When I changed it to:

```
val enumClass = Class.forName(Charsets.class.getName())
                     .asSubclass(Enum.class);
```

I got this error:

[image]

What's suprising is that the code compiles fine, and test that uses it passes.

I am unsure whether it is a bug in the Lombok Plugin, IDE or if I am doing something wrong. Shouldn't Lombok be able to easily infer the correct type of the variable?

My question is: can I use that code safely or should I revert to the original?

I am using the most recent (at this time) InteliiJ:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3
>
> Build #IU-163.7743.44, built on November 17, 2016
>
> JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b2 amd64
>
> JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

and Lombok Plugin:

> Lombok Plugin
>
> Version: 0.13.16

Comment: it's an experimental feature and, possibly, the plugin that IDEA uses doesn't support all experimental functionality yet

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yes, I am aware of that, but I have been using it for some time now and never encountered this issue before.

Comment: Also, delombok doesn't seem to work with this one, so it would be good to know what is generated under the covers.

Comment: It seems that the return type of `asSubClass` is not inferred correctly by intellij. You could use a type hint e.g. `.<Enum>asSubclass(Enum.class)` and the error disappears. Then of course intellij shows a weak warning that "Explicit type arguments can be inferred". Argh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirmed to work with *IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1* and *Lombok Plugin 0.17-2018.1*

Answer (score 5):

`Preferences > Plugins` **>** install the latest version of **Lombok** plugin for **IntelliJ**